# Adding X amount of minutes to past UNIX TIMESTAMP

Tags: php

I have a field in my DB that records the last time a check occured, I also have frequency of how often the checks should occur.

What I need is: I get the past timestamp and I need to add the frequency in minutes to it to check against current time stamp.

Can't think of a way via PHP, anyone could help?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL?

Comment: This is probably best handled directly in the database, without involving PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@fredley commented with just the right answer:

> timestamp += minutes * 60

Answer (score 2):

If you still want a plain PHP variant of that why not try [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

```
//$oldTimestamp;
$minutes = 15;    
$newTimestamp = strtotime('+ ' . $minutes . ' minutes', $oldTimestamp);
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your database configuration, and table layout, you may want to look at the [MySQL ADDTIME function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime)

Comment: ...If the OP is using MySQL.  That's not yet been indicated.

Comment: Yes... That's why I made my answer conditional. Suppose a comment would have been better. My mistake.